# How to remove intellisense suggestions in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I recently had a bug in Firefox due to me choosing the wrong script type with intellisense.

```
<script type="text/jscript">
```

vs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Is it possible to remove options from intellisense?

EDIT: I still want statement completion, just not all the options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a look at the `.xsd` files in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\` (your directory structure will vary obviously, based on your OS bitness and system drive letter), you'll find several instances of the string `text/jscript`.

Use Visual Studio to do a find in files across the whole directory and remove values of `<xsd:enumeration value="text/jscript" />`, that should eliminate it from Visual Studio's intellisense.

**Note:** *I recommend taking a copy of the files first*

Comment: I've removed the "I think"/"haven't tried it yet", as I have, and it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Tools ---> Options ----> Text Editor ----> All Languages

Uncheck statement completion.

Comment: I still want statement completion, just not all the options.

Comment: I don't think that's precisely what the OP's after, I'm guessing they want to be able to remove "text/jscript" from the list of options presented by intellisense, not nuke it entirely

Comment: Ah sorry. For individual options, Rob's solution seems great. I've never experimented it with removing the individual options, but always assumed it was possible via the .xsd files.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Code Snippets Manager...